# "Failed to get HEAD" error when pulling from Stash repo with GitHub Desktop

Tags: git, github, git-pull, bitbucket-server, github-desktop

I'm using GitHub Desktop to work with repos in Atlassian Stash. For publishing my own repos, I:

1. Create a new empty repo in Stash
2. Add my local directory in GitHub Desktop
3. Set its origin to my Stash URL (under Repository > Repository Settings...)
4. Publish

This works fine.

However, sometimes I simply want to clone existing Stash repos to my local machine. GitHub Desktop has a Clone option, of course, but it only works directly with your GitHub.com account; you can't enter an arbitrary URL to clone from. So instead, I thought I would be able to follow a procedure similar to what I use for publishing:

1. Add a local empty directory
2. Set its origin to the Stash URL
3. Pull

But when I do this, I always get a "failed to get HEAD" error.

Why can't I simply pull a Stash repo locally?

Comment: What happens when you try a different Git client? Or Git CLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pull in an empty (non-git) repo.

You can simply clone the Stash repo:

```
cd /path/to/repos
git clone /url/stash/myrepo
cd myrepo
git log
```

Then you have a local folder `/path/to/repos/myrepos`, that you can use in GitHub Desktop (Step 2 and 3 of your first procedure).

Comment: Ah, right. But so I have to clone from the command line then? There doesn't appear to be a way to clone from an arbitrary (non-GitHub) URL within GitHub Desktop.

Comment: Exactly: this is one of those cases where you need to fall back to the command line and clone manually.